# command in wsimport, error: -Xnocompile is an invalid option or argument

Tags: java, cmd, wsimport, cisco-axl

Good afternoon everyone
I have some problem.. 
I tried to export cisco library to my java project using cmd `wsimport` command
but an error message appears when i run this:

```
wsimport -keep -b schema/current/AXLSOAP.xsd -Xnocompile -s src -d bin -verbose schema/current/AXLAPI.wsdl
```

I get this error:

```
error: -Xnocompile is an invalid option or argument
```

I also tried searching on google, they said that by default this `-Xnocompile` command default value is false..
my assumption it means this command disable by default..

Is there any solution to solve this problem?
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

okay i'm found the solution, 
you can find -Xnocompile command in wsimport that located in 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\wsimport

the solution is just force it run in your java project
get into project directory using cmd then run the ws import with this command

```
C:\Users\VanTz\workspace\EM> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\wsimport"  -keep -b schema/current/AXLSoap.xsd -Xnocompile -s src -d bin -verbose schema/current/AXLAPI.wsdl
```

it works